# How to interpret: WCF Performance counters Calls per second and Calls Duration

Tags: wcf, performancecounter

I am monitoring two performance counters for WCF at an operation level:
- Calls Duration
- Calls Per Second

I have setup a sampling interval for the data counter logs in perfmon. I am not sure how to interpret these counters.

So assume that we are sampling every one second. 

From MSDN:

Calls Duration:

The average duration of calls to this operation. The average duration is calculated based on this equation: (N1-N0)/(D1-D0).

Calls Per Second:

Number of calls to this operation in a second.

This counter is of performance counter type PERF_COUNTER_COUNTER, whose value is calculated using the following formula.

(N 1 - N 0 ) / ( (D 1 -D 0 ) / F) 


I have the log for both these performance counters for a duration of an hour.
Sample Log for Calls Duration:

```
Timestamp              Call Duration
06/25/2012 17:58:52.755 0.05476632
06/25/2012 17:58:53.753 0
06/25/2012 17:58:54.751 0
06/25/2012 17:58:55.765 0
06/25/2012 17:58:56.764 0.058265824
06/25/2012 17:58:57.762 0
06/25/2012 17:58:58.760 0
06/25/2012 17:58:59.758 0
06/25/2012 17:59:00.757 0
06/25/2012 17:59:01.755 0
06/25/2012 17:59:02.753 0
06/25/2012 17:59:03.752 2.90697808
```

Sample Log for: Calls Per Second:

```
Timestamp              Calls per second
06/25/2012 17:48:08.752 1.001692492
06/25/2012 17:48:09.750 0
06/25/2012 17:48:10.764 0.986190617
06/25/2012 17:48:11.762 1.00156982
06/25/2012 17:48:12.761 0
06/25/2012 17:48:13.759 0
06/25/2012 17:48:14.757 0.994411867
06/25/2012 17:48:15.756 0
06/25/2012 17:48:16.754 0
```

What I would like to answer from this data is:

How many calls out of "n" number of calls took say more than 2 seconds?

More information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/09/07/how-to-use-performance-counters-to-diagnose-performance-of-wcf-applications.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(N1-N0)/(D1-D0)** means **(DataFromSample2 - DataFromSample1) / (TimeAtSample2 - TimeAtSample1)**

So the values you are getting for Call Duration and Calls per second is average of current sample and previous sample and these counters can't tell "How many calls out of "n" number of calls took say more than 2 seconds?".

You can create you customer counter value, refer [LINK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamhems/archive/2008/12/04/using-custom-performance-counters-to-measure-multi-threaded-operation-durations.aspx)